# Vergleicht „eine der besten X-innen der Welt" nur Frauen?

Tags: gender-neutrality

[Lanz präsentiert Sarah Willis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IL7vajdgIh4&t=8s) als

> ...eine der besten Hornistinnen der Welt

Ich glaube, er meint sie sei „eine der Besten, unter allen Hornisten“ (auch männlich).  Nach meinem Gefühl klingt nicht so wirklich neutral, sondern als ob er nur beim Vergleich Hornisten ausschließen würde. Dabei hätte er wohl deutlicher den Vergleichspunkt wählen können.

Was meint der Satz wirklich? Wäre es falsch „Hornistinnen“ durch „Hornisten“ zu ersetzen?

(Wenn ein Hornist und 99 Hornistinnen spielen, nutzt man in meiner Muttersprache für die 100 Spielenden die männliche Form. Daher ist wohl manchem der Ursprung dieser Frage unklar.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115448/discussion-on-question-by-c-p-vergleicht-eine-der-besten-x-innen-der-welt-nur).

Answer (score 5):

Die grammatische Analyse ist klar: da ist die Rede von einer Gruppe der "besten Hornistinnen der Welt", und davon sei Frau Willis "eine".

Da es kein generisches Femininum gibt, kann die Gruppe der "besten Hornistinnen der Welt" nur Frauen umfassen. Wenn Lanz alle Hornisten und Hornistinnen meinte, hat er es also falsch formuliert.

Die Frage, wie man es formulieren müsste, wenn man sie mit allen Hornisten und Hornistinnen vergleichen wollte, führt zu der Frage, wie man zum in der überlieferten Sprache vorhandenen generischen Maskulinum steht, das in den letzten Jahrzehnten ausgehend von der Frauenbewegung von vielen als diskriminierend abgelehnt, aber auch von vielen als sprachlich eleganter verteidigt wird.

Generisches Maskulinum wäre:

> Sie ist **einer** der besten **Hornisten** der Welt

oder

> Sie ist **eine** der besten **Hornisten** der Welt

(Die Meinungen dazu, was von beiden stimmt, scheinen hier im Forum geteilt zu sein, und ich habe keine Quelle gefunden, die das klärt.)

Mit einer der neueren Formen (modifiziertes Femininum mit Binnen-I oder Stern):

> Sie ist eine der besten HornistInnen der Welt
> Sie ist eine der besten Hornist*innen der Welt

Üblich sind auch Umformulierungen, die das Problem zu vermeiden versuchen:

> Sie gehört zum Kreis der besten Hornistinnen und Hornisten der Welt
> Sie ist Hornistin und gehört in ihrem Fach zu den Besten der Welt.

Ob in diesem Beruf eine Partizip-Präsens-Fassung genutzt wird ("Hornspielende" o.ä.), wie es für manch andere Bezeichnungen üblich geworden ist, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: Selbstverständlich gibt es das generische Femininum, es ist allerdings bislang zugegeben ziemlich selten in "offizieller", bzw "geschriebener" Sprache. Man sollte auch beachten, dass Lanz sich hier in einem Gespräch befindet und in seiner Sendung auf Sprachökonomie achtet. Er also eben doch (unbewusst) das generische Femininum nutzte, da andere Formulierungen holprig wirken können.

Comment: @mtwde: Es gibt generische Feminina, aber nicht wie Du Dir das vorstellst. "Hornistin" ist ja eine markierte Form, die weibliche Hornisten bezeichnet. Das Wort "Hornist" ist männlich und bezeichnet kein Geschlecht, sondern eine Funktion, eine Aufgabe, Rolle, einen Beruf. Ein weibliches Generikum ist "Person". Die Person heißt es, das Wort ist weiblich und sagt auch nichts über das Geschlecht desjenigen, der es erfüllen kann. Männer sind nicht am Rande irgendwie mitgemeint, obwohl das Wort weiblich ist, sondern genauso gemeint wie Frauen. Obwohl es als schwarzer Schwan ins Auge fallen müsste …

Comment: …, kommt kaum ein Laie selbst in einer Diskussion auf dieses Wort, obwohl es nicht selten ist. Würden die Hypothesen der feminist. Sprachforschung stimmen, dann dürfte es das Wort gar nicht geben im Deutschen. Jedem Leser und Hörer müsste es querliegen im Sprachgefühl, aber das tut es nicht, es liegt geschmeidig in der Sprache wei andere weibliche Generika, die nur nicht oder selten den homo sapiens sapiens bezeichnen: Die Katze, die Maus, die Taube. Beim sächlichen Mitglied stößt man sich nur an der Pennälerassoziation vom männlichen Glied, das zu Sprachwitzen einlädt - nicht am Sächlichen.

Comment: Irgendwie war ja klar, dass man bei diesem Thema mit nicht mit Kommentar  begründeten Downvotes, sachlich zweifelhaften Edits ohne Begründung und ideologischen Kommentaren rechnen musste. Wenn jemand der Meinung ist, dass "Hornistinnen" in der deutschen Schriftsprache für eine Gruppe von Hornisten verschiedener Geschlechter stehen kann, möge dafür doch bitte eine glaubhafte sprachwissenschaftliche Quelle (außerhalb des feministischen Aktivismus) nennen.

Comment: @HalvarF: Das einfachste Beispiel wäre wohl: Nachfolgenden bezeichnen wir mit Hornistinnen Hornspielende aller Geschlechtsidentitäten.

Comment: @infinitezero: Beispiel wofür? Ich weiß gerade nicht, worauf du dich beziehst. Etwas umdefinieren kann man immer, das ist ja kein Hinweis auf den normalen Sprachgebrauch, eher im Gegenteil.

Comment: Beispiel hierfür: Wenn jemand der Meinung ist, dass "Hornistinnen" in der deutschen Schriftsprache für eine Gruppe von Hornisten verschiedener Geschlechter stehen kann. Von normalem Sprachgebrauch war da nie die Rede. Desweiteren ist Sprache kein statisches Konstrukt und es gibt keine Gesetze die etwas festlegen. Grammatikalische Richtlinen, Rechtschreibung und der gleichen sind nicht in Stein gemeißelt sonder unterliegen einem Wandel. Daher halte ich auch den Schluss "Lanz halt falsch formuliert" für ... falsch. Der Kontext und die heutige Sensibilisierung für Genderthemen fehlt hier.

Comment: @infinitezero: Sprache ist nichts anderes als eine Gesamtheit von Konventionen. Sonst bräuchten wir diese ganze Website hier nicht. Wenn du sagst, das Wort Tisch könne im Deutschen auch für Stühle stehen, kannst du als Beispiel dafür nicht sinnvoll den Satz "Mit dem Wort Tisch bezeichnen wir in diesem Text Möbel mit vier Beinen aller Art" anführen.
Die Spekulation, dass ausgerechnet ein Markus Lanz hier ein generisches Femininum gemeint haben könnte und nicht einfach nur etwas schlampig formuliert hat, halte ich für sehr weit hergeholt.

Comment: Es gibt Wörterbücher, Grammatikbücher, Linguisten etc., die die Sprache ständig beobachten und beschreiben. Nicht die Sprache, die sich Aktivisten manchmal wünschen oder zu der hin sie aus gut gemeinten politischen Erwägungen den Diskurs verschieben wollen, sondern die Sprache, die benutzt und verstanden wird, mit der man einen Sprachtest besteht, die man als Sprachlehrer lehren soll, etc. In dieser Sprache bezeichnet im Jahr 2020 das Wort "Hornistinnen" eine Gruppe von Frauen.

Comment: Eine Sprache ohne Kontext beurteilen zu wollen, halte ich für den völlig falschen Ansatz. Der Kontext ist häufig das überhaupt erst notwendige Mittel, die Bedeutung einzelner Wörter korrekt zu erschließen (Homonyme und Satire sind die ersten Beispiele die einfallen). Ich halte die Frage ohnehin für Meinungsbehaftet und der einzige, der sie zweifelsohne beantworten kann, ist Lanz.