# How to translate sentences like "One of the fastest cars on the market" or "One of the biggest disasters in history..."?

Tags: comparative

I always struggle with these types of sentences in German as I'm not sure how exactly the declension of the indefinite article is decided. For example, I would normally write a sentence like "one of the most beautiful places I've visited" as "einer der schönsten Orte, die ich besucht habe", but it's purely by guessing. Can someone direct me to an explanation on how to construct these when dealing with different gendered nouns in singular and plural?

Comment: [This](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/61409/43989) question seems related.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you perceive this as more complex than it is: eine/eines/einer is singular. Even if it is one of many, it stays singular.

So it is:

- der Ort, also *einer* (your translation is correct)
- das Auto, also *eines der schnellsten Autos* (oder *einer der schnellsten Wagen*)
- das Unglück also *eines der schlimmsten Unglücke* (assuming *Unglück* has a plural at all, which is debatable)
- die Waschmaschine, also *eine der sparsamsten Waschmaschinen*.

Note, that the principle is not special in respect to superlatives as in:

> Ich nahm eines der Autos aus dem Fuhrpark.

Comment: Thanks! So basically I just need to remember these three possibilities (eine/eines/einer) and so long as I know the right gender of the noun I can't go wrong.

Comment: Would you mind to complete your answer with an example of a feminine noun?

Comment: Maybe *Eine der größten Katastrophen der Geschichte...* for "“One of the biggest disasters in history…”? I think *schlimmst* is more like "worst" and *Unglück* is more like "misfortune". It would be an example with a feminine noun if nothing else..